# Why is this outputting goodbye, (random letter/number) & not the intended entered integer?

Tags: c, cs50

I am trying to understand why this is outputting what looks like a mapped alphabet when the **goodbye**, () section is trigger and not when the hello, section is.

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
    int x = get_int("integer: ");

    if (x <= 10){
       printf("hello, %x\n",x);
    }
    else if (x > 10){
       printf("goodbye, %x\n",x);
    }
}
```

Comment: program depends on user input which you didn't pointed in question.

Comment: It is because the "hello" section outputs when `x <= 10` so the single decimal digit is the same as the single hexadecimal digit (unless you entered **10**). However when `x > 10` (actually `x >= 10`) you will see the letters `A` to `F` used too (in many cases, but not all).

Comment: Please edit your question and include the results of inputting the following values: 0, 1, 9, 10. Thanks.

Comment: wdc gave me the correct reply for this already is was because i used %x instead of %d,clearly something i know i need more knowledge on now. But for anyone who still wants to know the User input was just a simple Integer or whole number & the answers to those following values were 
hello, 0
hello, 1
hello, 9
hello, a

Answer (score 1):

If you want to output an integer, use `%d`, instead of `%x`. `%x` is a format specifier for printing hexadecimal numbers. You can learn more about format specifiers [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/).

Comment: thanks that seemed to do the trick if you dont mind could you tell me the difference between the two?

Comment: `%d` prints Decimal and `%x` prints heXadecimal. Read the docs.

Comment: In `hex`, `10 = A`, `11 = B`, and so on till `15 = F`. Then the cycle restarts from `0`.